# JQuery/Javascript: Client side modification of asp.net datagrid output to allow tablesorter to work

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, tablesorter

The output of the asp.net datagrid doesn't include the thead and tbody elements required for the jquery tablesorter to work.

E.g. it looks like this:

```
    <table>
        <tr>this is my header row</tr>
        <tr>content row 1</tr>
        <tr>content row 2</tr>
        <tr>content row 3</tr>
        ...
        <tr>content row n</tr>
    </table>
```

and it needs to look like this:

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>this is my header row</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>content row 1</tr>
            <tr>content row 2</tr>
            <tr>content row 3</tr>
            ...
            <tr>content row n</tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I knocked up the following javascript to dynamically insert them, but the table is still not sortable.
I've confirmed that if I manually insert the thead and tbody tags directly into the output html, the table is sortable, but when I try to do it using the DOM, it doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing?

```
    $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            var tbl = document.getElementById('mytableid');

            // new header and body elements to be inserted
            var tblHead = document.createElement('thead');
            var tblBody = document.createElement('tbody');
            // get the first row and the remainder
            var headerRow = $(tbl).find('tr:first')
            var bodyRows  = $(tbl).find('tr:not(:first)');

            // remove the original rows
            headerRow.remove();
            bodyRows.remove();

            // add the rows to the header and body respectively
            $(tblHead).append(headerRow);
            $(tblBody).append(bodyRows);

            // add the head and body into the table
            $(tbl).append(tblHead);
            $(tbl).append(tblBody);

            // apply the tablesorter
            $(tbl).tablesorter(); 
        } 
    );
```

EDIT: I actually solved the problem before I posted the question, but I thought I'd go ahead and post it anyway, as it may be useful to others...
See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, a phantom <tbody> element appears in the output. The trick is to ensure that it is removed before adding in the generated ones...
Hopefully this will be useful to someone!

```
    $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            var tbl = document.getElementById('mytableid');

            // new header and body elements to be inserted
            var tblHead = document.createElement('thead');
            var tblBody = document.createElement('tbody');
            // get the first row and the remainder
            var headerRow = $(tbl).find('tr:first')
            var bodyRows  = $(tbl).find('tr:not(:first)');

            // remove the original rows
            headerRow.remove();
            bodyRows.remove();

            // SOLUTION HERE: 
            // remove any existing thead/tbody elements
            $(tbl).find('tbody').remove();
            $(tbl).find('thead').remove();

            // add the rows to the header and body respectively
            $(tblHead).append(headerRow);
            $(tblBody).append(bodyRows);

            // add the head and body into the table
            $(tbl).append(tblHead);
            $(tbl).append(tblBody);

            // apply the tablesorter
            $(tbl).tablesorter(); 
        } 
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code still doesn't address the cells in the header.  To convert them from  tags to  tags you can add this:

`$('thead tr td').each(function(i) {
                $(this).replaceWith("<th>" + $(this).html() + "<\/th>");
            });`

Comment: It's been a while since I did this, but I think I may have tried that and found that the table sorter didn't like it...